# What is the meaning of “work behinds off”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

The following sentence is an excerpt from a video uploaded by the magazine TIME on YouTube, whose title is “TIME Person Of The Year: Joe Biden And Kamala Harris.” The sentence mentioned below focuses on problems about black people.

> Part of what I think settles some of these question is to work your behinds off for a more just America.

I do not know the meaning of the phrasal verb “work behinds off”. I had never seen the phrase before and tried to seek any information about it on the Internet, but I couldn’t.

Would you mind telling me the meaning of the phrase?

Answer (score 3):

Your behind is your backside or buttocks, commonly ass: [**Work one's ass off**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/work-your-ass-off).

Also, in this context, work your tush or tail off, bust your hump or chops

> Per Hot Licks: "Work hard, to the point of exhaustion." The adverb *off* indicates *to the extreme*.